# Find strings from a list starting with strings in another list

Tags: python, string, list

I have two list `listOne` & `listTwo`

**e.g.**

`listOne` could contain 'about', 'day', 'school'

`listTwo` could contain 'a','c','da','z'

I want to find out all the elements in `listOne` which start with characters from elements in `listTwo`. The output with above example is 'about' and 'day'

I try to implement it with following code:

```
for elem1 in listTwo:
    for elem2 in listOne:
        if elem2.startswith(elem1):
            result.append(elem2)
```

but I feel it nested too much. Is there a more elegant way to achieve it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you're doing it is fine.  It's easy to read/understand, etc.

However, if you really want, you can probably condense it down using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
result = [elem2 for elem1, elem2 in product(listTwo, listOne) if elem2.startswith(elem1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I am looking for. Where should I do the `result.append(elem1)`?

Comment: @Leem.fin -- You don't need it.  Just assign the list comprehension to `result`...

Comment: I run the code, the output is ['a', 'da'], but I need ['about', 'day']

Comment: @Leem.fin -- Then the code in your question is incorrect... You're appending `elem1` which comes from `listTwo` which doesn't have those words in it... However, the fix is easy.  Just change the first `elem1` to `elem2` and you're golden.

Comment: I think it's confusing that `elem1` is drawn from `listTwo` and `elem2` is drawn from `listOne`, but I do acknowledge is that this is exactly what the OP did in his question. :-}

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a tuple to `str.startswith` method.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswit):

> **str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]):** Return True if string starts
>   with the prefix, otherwise return False. prefix can also be a tuple of
>   prefixes to look for. With optional start, test string beginning at
>   that position. With optional end, stop comparing string at that
>   position.

**But this is supported in Python 2.5+**

```
tuple_listTwo = tuple(listTwo)

[ele for ele in listOne if ele.startswith(tuple_listTwo)]
```

**Output:**

> ['day', 'about']

Comment: Also, depending on the list sizes, you'll be a lot more efficient if you create the tuple _first_ (otherwise, you're recreating the same tuple over and over and over).

Comment: @mgilson,regarding your first comment, I think you had this notion based on OP's code. But I read the description and did this.

Comment: Yeah, I've redacted my first comment.  OP had the wrong code, but edited it to get the solution you've posted.